# Correct way to decode video chunks over sockets

Tags: python, reactjs, sockets, flask, webrtc

I am trying to send back the webcam footage of a user in real time over websockets

I have the following react code

```js
import { type } from "@testing-library/user-event/dist/type";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const VideoFeed = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState(null);
  const recordedChunksRef = useRef([]);
  const socket = useRef();
  const connected = useRef(false);


  function removeAudioFromStream(originalStream) {
    const videoTracks = originalStream.getVideoTracks();

    // Create a new MediaStream with only video tracks
    const videoOnlyStream = new MediaStream();
    videoTracks.forEach((track) => {
      videoOnlyStream.addTrack(track);
    });

    return videoOnlyStream;
  }

  const streamCamVideo = () => {
    const constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1920, height: 1080 } };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then((stream) => {

        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        mediaRecorder.start(1000); // where 1000 is the interval
        console.log("MediaRecorder: ", mediaRecorder);
        videoRef.current.srcObject = removeAudioFromStream(stream);
        videoRef.current.removeAttribute("controls");
        videoRef.current.removeAttribute("audio");
        videoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
          videoRef.current.play();
        };
        setMediaStream(stream);


        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
          if (e.data.size > 0) {
            recordedChunksRef.current.push(e.data);

            console.log(recordedChunksRef.current.length);
          }
        };
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      });
  };


  //   // Handle data available from MediaRecorder
  //   const handleDataAvailable = (event) => {
  //     console.log("Triggered");
  //     if (e.data.size > 0) {
  //       recordedChunksRef.current.push(e.data);
  //     }
  //   };
  // };
  const stopCamVideo = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.pause();
    }
  };

  const playCamVideo = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.play();
    }
  };


  // Send recorded video chunks to the server
  const sendVideoChunks = () => {
    if (recordedChunksRef.current.length > 0) {
      console.log("Emitting blob");
      const blob = new Blob(recordedChunksRef.current, {
        type: "video/webm",
      });

      // Send the blob as a binary message over WebSocket
      socket.current.emit("video_frame", blob);
      recordedChunksRef.current = [];
    }
  };

  const endCamVideo = () => {
    if (mediaStream) {
      const tracks = mediaStream.getTracks();
      tracks.forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
      });
      videoRef.current.srcObject = null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Perform any additional setup or side effects here
    if (connected.current == false) {
      socket.current = io("http://localhost:5000");
      connected.current = true;
    }
    socket.current.on("connect", () => {
      console.log(socket.current.connected);
    })

    socket.current.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log(socket.current.connected);

    })

    // socket.emit("stream", mediaStream);
    setInterval(sendVideoChunks, 100);
    // setInterval(sendVideoChunks, 1000);
    return () => {
      // Cleanup or remove any event listeners if needed
      // socket.current.close();
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="container">
        <video autoPlay={true} ref={videoRef}></video>
      </div>
      <br />
      <button onClick={streamCamVideo}>Start streaming</button>
      <button onClick={stopCamVideo}>Pause streaming</button>
      <button onClick={playCamVideo}>Continue streaming</button>
      <button onClick={endCamVideo}>End streaming</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoFeed;
```

and I have the following code for the python flask server

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
count = 0

@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connect():
    print("Client connected")

@socketio.on("disconnect")
def handle_disconnect():
    print("Client disconnected")

@socketio.on("video_frame")
def handle_video_frame(frame_blob):
    global count
    print("Received video frame")

    with open(f"video_received/{count}.webm", "wb") as f:
        f.write(frame_blob)
        count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host="localhost", port=5000)
```

i have tried appending the blob chunks into one big webm using the "ab" way to write to a file and have tried saving it individually.

When I save it individually there are some semi complete frames that seem to showcase proper image and audio but other than that it shows a black screen in vlc.